# Jasper Reports Fill Parameters in SQL Query

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, datasource, resultset

I have a web application which generates reports based off an SQL query. These SQL queries have Jasper Report parameters (i.e. $P{Param}).

In my Java code, I'm using PreparedStatement to execute the query and return a result set. I use this result set and change it into a JRResultSetDataSource to pass into JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperReport, parameters, dataSource).

The reason I'm using a data source and not a connection is so that I can use setQueryTimeout on my PreparedStatement.

My problem is that I need a way to fill in the query's parameters with the parameter map values.  Is there a built in way to do this?

Ex.

```
rawSqlString = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ROW1 = $P{Param}";
filledSqlString = somefunction(sqlString);
ResultSet rs = sqlStatement.executeQuery(filledSqlString);
```

I can't use the "rawSqlString" since it has $P{Param}.

Alternatively, is there a type of datasource which simply stores the unfilled SQL query which I can pass to JasperFillManager?

Normally JasperFillManager handles this but I want my query to timeout, so I need to use setQueryTimeout, and somehow convert this into a format Jasper can handle.

Comment: Which kind of parameters do you want to retrieve? Usually you should be the one filling the parameters map, so you should have that information in Java

Comment: Mainly strings and numbers, I do have access to the parameters map, but I wanted to know if there was some way to use Jasper to fill in the query.